# Is it possible to expose protected constants with the same name in an inherited class?

Tags: c#

Here's an example to illustrate:

```
namespace MyProject
{
    public abstract class MyAbstractThing
    {
        protected const uint Percentage = 42;
    }

    public sealed class MyThing : MyAbstractThing
    {
        public new const uint Percentage = base.Percentage;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this won't compile, as it complains that I cannot access a static constant in a non-static context. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `base` keyword only applies in a non-static context, just like the `this` keyword. The `this` keyword refers to "this instance as its own type" and the `base` keyword refers to "this instance as its base class type." You cannot use `base` to refer to "the base class of this class."

You need to use `MyAbstractThing` instead, because you are in a static context.

```
namespace MyProject
{
    public abstract class MyAbstractThing
    {
        protected const uint Percentage = 42;
    }

    public sealed class MyThing : MyAbstractThing
    {
        public new const uint Percentage = MyAbstractThing.Percentage;
        //                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    }
}
```